# Нужно ли здесь ставить тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Невыносимо капризный ребенок. Сегодня он ест мясо, завтра — точно такое же — ни в какую не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Невыносимо капризный ребенок. Сегодня он ест мясо, завтра — точно такое же — ни в какую не будет.

**Знаки поставлены правильно,** "точно такое же" является вставкой и обособляется тире (вставочная интонация, увеличенные паузы, пониженный тон речи).

Сравнить:  Сегодня он ест мясо, завтра ни в какую (есть его) не будет. Бессоюзное сложное предложение, второе предложение неполное.

Comment: >> *"точно такое же" является вставкой* Это только если очень-очень захотеть.

Comment: Захотеть несложно. Вставные конструкции (слова, сочетания слов, предложения) выделяются скобками или тире. Они содержат дополнительные сведения, замечания, уточнения, пояснения, поправки к сказанному; разъясняют, толкуют основную часть высказывания  http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128

Comment: Да, но здесь "дополнительные сведения, замечания, уточнения" и т.д. можно разглядеть только вооружившись микроскопом.

Comment: Вставка - это авторское решение, любой фрагмент автор  может посчитать вставной конструкцией. Обособление здесь нужно? Да, конечно. Запятыми? Нет, этот знак не выделит  словосочетание должным образом.  Вот и вся история, к микроскопам отношения не имеющая.  Учтем еще, что текст разговорного характера, там  используется особо выразительная интонация.

Comment: Интуиция подсказывает, что что-то здесь не так. Попробую включить логику. Если "точно такое же" - вставка, то значит она уточняет "мясо". Но "мясо" пропушено во второй части. При чтении первая реакция на тире - это догадка, что далее следует уточнение к "завтра" ("точно такое же завтра"), и лишь дочитав до конца, с трудом понимаешь смысл прочитанного.

Comment: Это запись разговорной речи, рассчитанной на слуховое восприятие. В устной речи  вставка - это второй план, выделенный не только паузами, но и пониженным тоном. Такой текст надо слушать, чтобы определить  его достоинства  или недостатки. Ваш вариант нормальный, но в нём   меньше экспрессии, он длиннее, в нем нет двух планов, которые являются характерным признаком  разговорной речи, придают ей объемность и выразительность.

Comment: Вопрос, что тут первично: речь или текст. Пишите вы пьесу или рассказ. В рассказе - даже передавая прямую речь - я бы позаботился о ясном и быстром понимании текста.

Comment: А мне кажется, что и в рассказе надо постараться передать динамичность  разговорного текста персонажей.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, предложение построено неудачно. Как ни ставь знаки препинания - слова "точно такое же" затрудняют понимание. Предлагаю рассмотреть такой вариант (с сохранением разговорного стиля):

**Невыносимо капризный ребенок. Сегодня он ест мясо, завтра - ни в какую не будет, даже точно такое же".**